# Customizing Route in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue and I currently have a page setup that is in the folder structure:

```
/pages/tg/_tg_id.vue
```

The setup is working fine as going to `website.com/tg/<user-id>` resolves to the user's page based off ID.

I'm now being asked to include a username in the URL, but I still need the `id` as names change and some user's don't even have a name. As a solution I'd like the new URL structure to be:

```
website.com/tg/<user-id>/<any string>
```

So that we can use a link that has the username in it, purely for vanity purposes *(putting any string after the last slash should resolve in the exact same way)*.

I'm unsure of how to set something like this up, currently my `nuxt.config.js` file has no routing settings. Is there something I can add to settings to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Focos on the user id as the main parameter, and make the string that comes after optional. That's how most sites handle unique pages.
If you need it to work without the name, in React you can create two different routes that render the same component. Makes two pages, and have each render the same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only second option with username you can just rename your page to
/pages/tg/_tg_id/_username.vue

and thats it.

If you still need your first url too you can use https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module and define alias inside your page or by extending routes by hand.

Comment: Thanks I'll mark as solved when I have a chance to test tomorrow. I do need both.

Comment: I actually found that just having the file you mentioned first was enough to handle both situations, thanks.